# Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:4000/style.css"

Tags: templates, deno, oak

I am using deno, oak and denjucks. The file structure is as below -

```
index.html
index.ts
style.css
```

the code I have used are as below - 
 index.ts is-

```
import {Application, send} from "https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts";
import denjucks from "https://deno.land/x/denjucks/mod.js";
const app = new Application();
const HOST = "http://localhost";
denjucks.configure('', { autoescape: true });
const PORT = 4000;
let res = denjucks.render("index.html", {txt: "World"});
app.use(async (context) => {
  context.response.body = res;
  });

console.log(`Server started at: ${HOST}:${PORT}`);
await app.listen({ port: PORT });
```

index.html -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" type="text/css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{{txt}}</h1>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css -

```
body{
    background: tomato;   
}
```

when i execute code deno run --allow-all index.ts, in chrome developer tools console a warning message is coming - **Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:4000/style.css"**. and css code is not applying. 
The reason behind this fault is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

All your routes are serving `text/html`, since you're always responding with `denjucks.render("index.html", {txt: "World"});`, so when you request `style.css` you're' responding with `index.html`

You need to set up a [static file middleware](https://github.com/oakserver/oak#static-content) so `./style.css` can be served correctly.

```
app.use(async (context) => {
  await send(context, context.request.url.pathname, {
    root: `${Deno.cwd()}`
  });
});

app.use(async (context) => {
   context.response.body = res;
});
```

Comment: When I use avove code, in browser no page opens. It gives message - This localhost page can’t be foundNo webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:4000/
HTTP ERROR 404

Comment: what's the error code? Without stack trace it's impossible to help you.